# AngularJS I am trying to calculate the result of many inputs (ng-model) included inside nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and I'm trying to create a simple inventory control program for several products. I've been googling for a couple hours and browsed many questions but have not quite been able to get my code to work.

The formula that should be calculated for each product is:

- Final inventory = Initial Inventory + Production - Sales

Here is the code: http://codepen.io/swordf1zh/pen/zfwcB

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="inventory">
    <form role="form" class="row" ng-controller="ProdCtrl">
        <!-- Secciones -->
        <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="section in sections">
            <blockquote class="text-center">{{section.name}}</blockquote>
            <div ng-repeat="product in products">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">{{product.name}}</span>
                      <input type="number" 
                             class="form-control text-center" 
                             placeholder="Cantidad" 
                             ng-model="total" 
                             ng-change="calculate(section.id, product.id, total)">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <blockquote class="text-center">Final Inventory</blockquote>
            <div ng-repeat="product in products">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">{{product.name}}</span>
                      <p class="form-control text-center">{{product.total}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("inventory",[]);
app.controller("ProdCtrl", ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.sections = [
            {id:1, name:'Initial Inventory'},
            {id:2, name:'Production'},
            {id:3, name:'Sales'},
        ];
        $scope.products = [
            {id:1, name:'Prod1', total:0},
            {id:2, name:'Prod2', total:0},
            {id:3, name:'Prod3', total:0},
            {id:4, name:'Prod4', total:0}
        ];
        $scope.calculate = function( sectionId, productId, cantidad ){
            if( sectionId != 3 ){
                $scope.products[productId-1].total += cantidad;
            } else {
                $scope.products[productId-1].total -= cantidad;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Finally I made the code work by myself ( http://codepen.io/swordf1zh/pen/jFora ) but I would really appreciate if there is somebody with a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

There were problems in your js code

First you were comparing with section. It should have been sectionId in the if loop. Second the calculate method which recieves the argument as cantidad should be parsed to a Integer value.

So your [working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IFdvy)

And JS code which I changed (the calculate function)

```
   $scope.calculate = function( sectionId, productId, cantidad ){
     var inventoryEdit = parseInt(cantidad);
            if( sectionId != 3 ){
        $scope.products[productId-1].total += inventoryEdit;
      } else {
        $scope.products[productId-1].total -= inventoryEdit;
      }
   };
```

Comment: Bugfixes were corrected on previous edit. It only works ok for the first row but not for the rest.

Comment: Your edit missed the parseInt line that is their in the answer

Comment: I changed the type of the input from number to text in the HTML, so I think it is not necessary to add parseInt to the JS code. It is only working for values smaller than 10. Try 10 in the first input and the calculate will first sum 1 and then sum 10